# Show a form filled with Javascript variables in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript

[image]I have a page which takes data from a mysql database and exports it as JSON and then displays the data on a page using javascript.

That all works fine, but i also want to be able to edit the data, and so want to be able to display a form which is filled with the javascript variables generated from the json output from mysql. So instead of just showing the table of results, i want to show a form pre-filled with the current values from the json output.

I have tried several ways to display the form elements, using the method below it shows the code, but does display the name, if i take the input field out of the single quotes, nothing is displayed.

So the picture shows the information retrieved from the database but i would like to show the information in a form.

```
function displayEmployee1(data) {
var employee = data.item;
console.log(employee);
$('#fullName').text('<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="' + employee.number + '"/>');
console.log(employee.telephone);
```

Comment: Please explain this a little better

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of what you see would help?

Comment: Brilliant thank you, would you make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert html, so change:

```
$('#fullName').text(...
```

to:

```
$('#fullName').html(...
```

(Or rather than creating input elements on the fly I would probably create the entire form directly in the html and then just use JS to populate it with the values from the JSON, using `$("input[name='name']).val(employee.name)`, etc.)